# Calling Equals returns false every time, even when values are same (C#)

Tags: c#, xna, compare, equals

I have a problem in an Windows Forms application which uses a XNA screen. I want to see if a change happens to an object after completing multiple lines of code. If it does, it should add a * to the Title to tell the user the file did changes but hasn't saved.

To do that, I copy the object and after those lines I check if they are equal.

```
 MapSquare afterChange = TileMap.GetMapSquareAtPixel((int)mouseLoc.X,(int)mouseLoc.Y);
 MapSquare beforeChange = (MapSquare)afterChange.Clone();
 // code.....
 if (!Object.Equals(beforeChange,afterChange))
 parentForm.MapChanged = true; // this happens even when no changes happend
```

This mistake must be in my Clone Method I used with the Iclonable interface because even when I check equals right after copying it, it doesn't work.

```
public object Clone()
    {
        return new MapSquare(this);
    }
 private MapSquare(MapSquare squere)
    {
        this.LayerTiles = (int[])squere.LayerTiles.Clone();
        this.CodeValue = squere.CodeValue;
        this.Behavior = squere.Behavior;

    }
```

What's the mistake? I think it's in the layertiles array but I already tried many things there, so I don't know what to do. Or is there even a other much easier way to solve my problem?

Answer (score 5):

You would need to override [`Object.Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx) for your `MapSquare` type to make it compare equality based on the values.  By default, `Object.Equals` only returns true if the two variables refer to the same actual instance - not if they have the same member values.

If you plan to do this, I would recommend implementing [`IEquatable<MapSquare>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx), as well.

Comment: Make sure to override GetHashCode as well!

Comment: I thought Equals compares the fields and ReferenceEquals and the == operator compare if they point to the same instance. So is that wrong? What's the difference between Equals and ReferenceEquals then?  Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @RobinBetka Equals, for classes, will basically be the same as ReferenceEquals unless you override it.  You need to override Object.Equals to get member comparisons.  (With a struct, that is true, but not with classes).  If you override equals, you should also typically implement GetHashCode, etc.  See the docs linked for `IEquatable<T>`

Answer (score 1):

Unless you overload the equality operator, you are testing whether the two object *references* are equal, not whether they contain identical values.